# React Native Redux. State is being updated, yet the component is not being rerendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm working on an app with redux.

In the following snippet I toggle the appEnabled state:

```
...
render() {
    const { appEnabled } = this.props;
    const { updatePreferences } = this.props;

    return (
        <View style={styles.preferences}>
                <Text>App enabled: {appEnabled + ''}</Text>
                <Button onPress={() => updatePreferences({ appEnabled: !appEnabled })}>Toggle AppEnabled</Button>
        </View>)
}
```

Here are the mapping functions:

```
function mapStateToProps({ preferences }) {
    return {
        appEnabled: preferences.appEnabled,
    };
}

function mapDispatchProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getPreferences,
        updatePreferences: (preferences) => dispatch(updatePreferencesAction(preferences))
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(PreferenceScreen);
```

The updating of the state works fine. Yet the component's rerendering does not occur.

I know that common cause can be accidental state mutation. I made sure that reducer function returns new object each time:

```
export default function preferenceReducer(state = { ...defaultState }, action = {}) {
    // console.log("reduces is called")
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_PREFERENCES :
            return { ...state, ...action.preferences };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// Action creators
export function updatePreferencesAction(preferences) {
    return { type: UPDATE_PREFERENCES, preferences };
}
```

What could be the reason of the component not being rerendered in my case?

Comment: Are you using ```super(props)``` in your component constructor?

Comment: Yes. I made sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the full code, if you add a jsfiddle it's easier to help.

Anyway, your component seems fine and it should update when props change. The way you update your state in your reducer is the only thing that seems a bit odd. I can't tell the shape of your state just by looking a your reducer but, for instance, why are you doing `state = {...defaultState}` instead of `state = defaultState`?

`return {...state, ...action.preferences }` is also dubious. In most cases state is updated like this: `return { ...state, preferences: action.preferences }` since it makes the change your reducer is making much clearer.

I'd recommend you make these changes and then thoroughly debug with redux devtools.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
function mapStateToProps({ preferences }) {
return {
    appEnabled: preferences.appEnabled,
};
```

}

**To**

```
function mapStateToProps({ appEnabled }) {
return {
    appEnabled: appEnabled,
};
```